# Bootstrap - How to line up two tbody's properly?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue where lining up a table isn't working properly and I was wondering if anyones dealt with something like this before. I looked it up, but couldn't find anything addressing it. I'm using AngularJS and nested ng-repeats which is why I'm having some trouble with this (and need to nest them inside a table). My code is below:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead><tr>
                <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="blah in blah">
            <tr ng-repeat="blah2 in blah">
                <td>......</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
             <!--This is the end of "Table 1" in the diagram below-->
            <tbody ng-repeat="blah3 in blah4">
            <tr ng-repeat="blah5 in blah6">
              <td>.........</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <!--This is the end of "Table 2" in the diagram below-->
            </table>
```

I'm ending up with a result like this (note, I had to draw it due to the fact that the table data I'm using is sensitive information): [image]

How can I pull the second tbody (the smaller one) next to the first?

Thanks

Comment: You need 2 tables...

Comment: are you trying to align the columns or just the table width?

Comment: @Thorarins The width itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can simply use Bootstrap's columns as containers for your tables. For instance:

```
div.col-md-6
```

Will render two columns together until the screen collapse.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11692/

Comment: I took your advice and that's working great..except the tables are two different sizes so they don't line up properly. Is there a way to "stretch" (in height) to fit the other column

Comment: Yes, of course. In fact there are a lot of different ways to do this, it's all depends on how your preferences. You can either stretch the rows of the shorter table equally until the height of the shorter table match the taller one. Although on my opinion it would look pretty horrendous, visually-wise. One of the methods is to display an empty cells on the shorter table, for instance check updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11694/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the grid system of bootstrap ?

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
 </div>
```

I don't know what you want to put in the table but you can probably put it into the grid system. [link to doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Comment: That works great, and I was considering doing that, but is there a way to style it like a table? Can I just use the table classes?

Comment: This works but to me this is not a solution since you cannot use it like a table. Using 2 seperate tables with grid system classes would do the trick. Btw if you want to style it like a table just add the divs a custom class like "tableLike" and go to the bootstrap.css file to get the "table" or "table-hover" or "...table-whatever" classes' styles and just copy/paste it to your custom class style...

Comment: You can apply an extra class on the div with a border:1px solid #E1E1E1; for example. But if you want a table simply use one like :<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped"><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>

Comment: @Julo0sS I've ended up going with the tables, and wrapping them in columns worked great except the height is different so it doesn't line up. Is there a "stretch to fit" to the other table type thing?

Comment: use style="height:100%;" sometimes it can be a problem, but try it.

Comment: @Perry : No there is not. You'll have to fix heights manually (but this is not related to the use of the tables, that would be the same mess with divs), or deal with some javascript/jquery to make it dynamic...